# converts parts of a string to int in java

Tags: java, string, casting, int

I was wondering how can I take some numbers in a string and convert them to an integer type? for example if a user entered 12:15pm how can I get 1 and 2 and make an int with value 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the example above, you could try something like this:

```
final int value = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(':'))); //value = 12
```

Where `input = 12:15pm` in this case.

Generally speaking, just use a combination of `String#indexOf(String)`, `String#substring(int, int)` and `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Comment: Thanks just what I was after

Comment: @user2704743 Good. Perhaps you should try accepting the answer that you find most useful and solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Read the `String` and `Integer` API's

1. You can use the `String.split()` to get the two numeric strings
2. You can use `Integer.parseInt(...)` to convert the String to an int.

Edit: Using the split() you can do something like:

```
String time = "12:34pm";
int hour = Integer.parseInt( time.split(":")[0] );
```

Comment: Could I also use indexOf between 2 index numbers?

Comment: If you want. Play with both solutions to determine which you like better. You learn by trying.

Comment: I used the Integer.parseInt() method and inside I used the substring method then used the indexOf method to get the end of the substring this seemed to work, Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2704743, I asked if you tried the String.split() method. You don't learn anything when you just copy code people write for you.

Comment: I tried the string.split method, how can I store the 2 parts as 2 separate strings without using an array?

Comment: @user2704743, The method returns an array (so you can't change that) but you can access the first value of the array directly. See my edit. Again, this is not necessarily the solution you would use. It is just nice to know (and try) different solutions that may come in handy for other problems.

Comment: I ended up using the substring method