# getting a substring from an unknown string in java

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm wondering what is the best way to get a substring from a string which is undefined until a user enters the string. For example if the user enters 'abcdefg", how can I then get a substring "cde" I've looked at the indexOf method but this seems to be used when the string is already known

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What is the exact requirement? 1. the get the 3 characters after the first two? 2. To get the middle characters of a String? 3. To get 3 characters aftter "ab" is entered. 4. Something else? You already know how to use the substring(..) method. This is the problem you get when you just copy a solution (http://stackoverflow.com/q/18709601/131872) instead of thinking about the logic of the solution.

Comment: Ditto, but put simply: say how you want the part of the string chosen.

Comment: @user2704743, I'm asking you how to learn to post a proper question with a clear and understandable requirement. Your time would be better spent rewording and stating your requirement instead of making an unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `substring` method in the String class. In general, you should look at the javadocs for the class in question to see if there are any applicable methods for what you are trying to do.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

`substring` is easy to use.

```
String s = //something
s.substring(0, 3); //returns characters 0, 1 and 2 as a String
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` method to do that. But I am not clear what you are going to do here. you can use `indexOf()` method with some validation too.

For your example case you can try following.

*substring()*

```
   String str="abcdefg";
   System.out.println(str.substring(2,5));
```

*indexOf()* and *substring()*

```
   String str="abcdefg";
   if(str.indexOf('c')!=-1&&str.indexOf('e')!=-1){
       System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf('c'),str.indexOf('e')+1));
   }
```

*indexOf()* and *subSequence()*

```
  String str="abcdefg";
   if(str.indexOf('c')!=-1&&str.indexOf('e')!=-1){
       System.out.println(str.subSequence(str.indexOf('c'),str.indexOf('e')+1));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="abcdefg";
        if(str!=null && str.length() > 5)
            System.out.println(str.substring(2, 5));
        // OR
            System.out.println(str.subSequence(2, 5));

    }
}
```